# How can I get the complete documents inside a collection

Tags: python, arangodb

IIs there an option to read inside a `Collection` e.g. `students` the complete documents?
My aim is that I can see the complete documents inside a `dict`. e.g.:

```py
from arango import ArangoClient

# Initialize the ArangoDB client.
client = ArangoClient()

# Connect to database as  user.
db = client.db(<db>, username=<username>, password=<password>)

print(db.collections())
students = db.collection('students')
print(students)
```

Comment: You can get a list of all the documents in the collection by iterating it. `students = list(db.collection('students'))` or `students = db.collection('students').all()`

Comment: Thank you very much! With the first I got a `list` and with the second `<Cursor 285172>` - so the first one worked for me.